# How can i get all words of my text file using line.contains & array

Tags: java

My problem is that when I use this code I only get the last line of text containing my requested word, how can I get all the lines which includes the specific word I asked and later store them into `jTextArea` properly?

```
    try  {
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
       String line;

       while((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
           if(line.contains("Win")){
               jTextArea1.setText(line);
           }
       }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
} else {
    jTextArea1.setText("sup");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the method setText (). Every time you call setText() it **replaces** your Text Area. What you want to do is **append** so you need to call: `jTextArea.append(word)`

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to save the String to a List

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
...
if (line.contains("Win")) {
   words.add(line);
}
...
String output = StringUtils.join(words, "\n");
jTextArea1.setText(output);
```

The final few lines will join each word in the ArrayList using the new line token to join the words.